# OpenLDAP with two distinct ActiveDirectory "backends"

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I have the following setup in my organization:

- Sub organization A has a Microsoft Active Directory server that serves a "Windows only" world, i.e., it has **no** UID or GID values for its users. Users have fixed user names (e.g., "jdoe") and possibly changing email addresses "jane.doe@A.com" (might change to "jane.smith@A.com" on marriage...)
- Sub organization B has a Microsoft AD server that serves a "Unix aware" world, i.e. it has UID and GUID values for its users. User names are generally fixed and emails can change as above.

There can be a "jdoe" in sub both organizations, representing the same or different real-world people (in case the person is known to both sub organizations)

Now, I need to create an OpenLDAP setup that allows for the following:

- I'm living in sub organization C.
- Users can login using some sort of unique ID (e.g., A\jdoe or jdoe@A) and their password from their sub organization.
- For users from sub organization A, some sort of "automatic" UID has to be created. A certain range of UIDs with sufficient space can be assumed (e.g., 40k-80k).
- Any group information from sub organization A and B can be discarded but I need to have (Unix-style) groups in sub organization C that contains the users from A and B.
- Ideally, I would like to have a "manual sync and save" between the AD of A and B and my OpenLDAP server such that

  - I can authenticate users although the connection to AD of A and B might break.
  - Users that are flagged as "disabled" are also marked as disabled in my OpenLDAP after sync
  - Nothing has to be written back to the AD of A and B but changes from AD A and AD B have to be written back to my OpenLDAP server.

On a high level, what is the best practive approach for this? What are the relevant terms to look for in the documentation and books about LDAP/OpenLDAP. Not being an expert in LDAP/OpenLDAP it appears to be that there is a lot of domain-specific language used anywhere that people write about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by creating an OpenLDAP instance that I feed the necessary account information into. Password-based authentication is implemented by using an LDAP proxy with two backends.